# PHP Frameset with ASP.NET frame resulting lost session

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a web application which is PHP Frameset , with left frame(menu)  and right frame (content).

2 week ago,my boss request me add a menu item on left frame and hyperlink to another asp.net page on right frame. using GET to login in the asp.net web application.

for example

```
<a href="login.aspx?src=php&action=login&username=john&password=123456">Menu Item</a>
```

I using Firebug and SQL Server Profiler to monitoring the activity.
at very first, the login.aspx have success query from database and add the login info to ASP.NET Session and response.redirect to main.aspx.

But after redirect to main.aspx, the session will lost.

I have search over on Google, somebody said that the problem is cause because ASP.net cannot be embed into frame, but none of them have solution.

So, anybody know how to preserve the Session?

Comment: Does your `login.aspx` destroy/overwrite the session, intentionally or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a [P3P compact policy header](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2007/08/aspnet-loss-of-session-cookies-with.html) to the child content should work

Here is a simple, compact policy that should work (Global.asax):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");
```

**References**

- [Loses session state in iframe, but not in pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759706/loses-session-state-in-iframe-but-not-in-pop-up-window)
- http://kiranpatils.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/session-lost-in-iframe/
- [P3P Project Home](http://www.w3.org/P3P/)
- [Wikipedia Article on P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P)

Comment: Note: This will almost certainly be easier with an iframe, rather than a frameset